# custom setcookie implementation with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, setcookie, pecl

I'm trying to override the setcookie implementation using the test_helpers PECL extension without any luck.

```
    $username = 'test';
    set_setcookie_overload(function() { error_log('setcookie called'); return FALSE; });
    setcookie('username', $userName, time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
    unset_setcookie_overload();
```

I get this error:
        PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function set_setcookie_overload()

I verified that the extension is working well with the example here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers

Thanks.

**Update:** For further clarification, it sounds like the test_helpers extension allows to override in-built PHP functions like setcookie. In the link above, the author has provided an example to override the exit method using set_exit_overload(). I'm trying to do the same for setcookie() using set_setcookie_overload() without any luck.

Comment: I didn't see anything relating to `setcookie()` at the link you provided, and a search for `set_setcookie_overload` yielded only a single link to this question.

Comment: David, it sounds like the test_helpers extension allows to override in-built PHP functions like setcookie. In the link mentioned, the author has provided an example to override the exit method using set_exit_overload. I'm trying to do the same for setcookie() using set_setcookie_overload() without any luck. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Oh I see now. I saw the examples and searched for cookie, but this is more generic. How did you verify that the extension works--via CLI or Apache? They have separate configs usually. Does it work using `php -a` interactively?

Comment: David, set_exit_overload() works using php cli and within phpunit tests, but set_cookie_overload() doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that are available in can be found in the source [**`over at github`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers/blob/master/test_helpers.c#L380). Everything starting with `PHP_FUNCTION` is exposed to the user to call.

So yeah. There just is no `set_setcookie_overload()` in php-test-helpers. You have to find another workaround.

Sadly `rename_function` can't help you either as it doesn't work with internal functions.

[Complete function list of the test_helpers extension](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers/blob/master/test_helpers.c#L556)

Comment: Thanks edorian, it sounds like I'm out of luck. I'd have to look for other approaches.

Comment: It might not be too hard to modify and compiled yourself. Otherwise submit a pull request. I'm on vacation or I'd be curious to try it myself. :)